# Read-only column with Linq2DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, orm, linq2db

In my SQL Server table, I have a computed column. So for that column, I want to have only reading statements (like 'select') and no writing statements (like 'update') in generated code by Linq2DB.

What is the easiest way to do it?

I don't want to all update/add statements explicitly to prevent writing to this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[Column(SkipOnUpdate=false, SkipOnInsert=false)]` attribute.